# NextJS Fast refresh not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, next.js, chakra-ui, fast-refresh

I am building a website with nextjs and Chakra UI. I am using emotion to style my navigation.

The code of navigation component is as follows:

```
import Link from "next/link";
import { Flex, List, ListItem } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import Image from "next/image";
import styled from "@emotion/styled";

const Nav = styled.nav`
  position: sticky;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 2;
`;

export default function StickyNav() {
  return (
    <Nav>
      <Flex
        bg='gray.100'
        justifyContent='space-between'
        p='8'
        borderRadius='16'
      >
        <Image src='/vercel.svg' alt='Vercel Logo' width={72} height={16} />
        <List display='flex' ml='4'>
          <ListItem mr='8'>
            <Link href='#about'>
              <a>About</a>
            </Link>
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem mr='8'>
            <Link href='#projects'>
              <a>Projects</a>
            </Link>
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem>
            <Link href='#contact'>
              <a>Contact</a>
            </Link>
          </ListItem>
        </List>
      </Flex>
    </Nav>
  );
}
```

I am having trouble with Fast refreshing. When I start the dev server, the Navigation component picks up the styles correctly

```
const Nav = styled.nav`
  position: sticky;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 2;
`;
```

after serving, if I try to change the top position to `10px` the fast refresh doesn't reflect those changes.

The fast refresh feature is working perfectly with other components but has problem with this specific component only. I have looked through several articles but not sure what's causing this behavior.

Answer (score 11):

Check filename or foldername not started with a uppercase

Fast-refresh not works :

[image: Fast-refresh not works]

fast-refresh works :

[image: Fast-refresh not works]

Comment: This doesn't make any sense as to why it would change anything.

Answer (score 8):

Also check if your import statement has right casing.

```
import Box from '../Components/box';
```

vs

```
import Box from '../Components/Box';
```

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. I think upper and lowercase can be confusing for beginners.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and looked up the names of the imports. In my layout.jsx file, I was importing the Nav component like this: `import Nav from "@/components/nav";` which was the main issue to stop fast refresh. I changed this to `import Nav from "@/components/Nav";` and the fast refresh is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

In local my fast refresh was not working for next 13 version. I just upgraded node  and npm version. It is working now.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, the two words filename should use dash `-`, rather than underscore `_`.

For example:

good filename: `hello-world.js`

bad filename: `hello_world.js`

Answer (score 0):

As @new2cpp and DeadBoyPiotrek Stated

When Importing your headers make sure your import statements match the file names.

*Navbar.js <--Example File name*

***import Navbar from "../components/Navbar"***

**Not**

***import Navbar from "../components/navbar"***

When I made this mistake the Fast Refresh would initially load then after changing something the Fast Refresh would continue rebuilding but never finish.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33522398)